# What's the difference between 'Albergue' and 'Hostal'?

Tags: sustantivos, topónimos

Is there any difference between the two words? Would they both be acceptable and understandable in Spain or maybe you'd use one based on location?

I suspect one may be used more often in the context of a homeless shelter where as the other for a youth hostel. For a traveler, which would be best suited as a reference to the place they're staying in on their travels?

Comment: hostal is a hostel. albergue is an inn.[on **their** travels, by the way]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [this page](https://blog.trabber.com/2016/02/diferencia-hotel-hostal-hostel-albergue/) there is useful information about the differences between *hotel, hostal, hostel, albergue*. There is also *hostería*, which is usually a small hotel, with few beds.

"hostal" is a cheap hotel, similar to "hostería".

"albergue" is similar to "hostel", where bathrooms are shared, never private.

Comment: +1 Some of these could be subject to regionalisms, no? I'd like to see a compendium with photographs- in América del Sur there's a spectacular gamma of temporary lodgings for every tast  from rastafari to "suit and tie" road warrior.